# Multple processes with i3wm

Tags: mate, i3-wm

I am setting up i3wm. 
In my config file I put:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id mate-settings-daemon
exec_always --no-startup-id mate-power-manager   
exec_always --no-startup-id nm-applet
```

I am using ubuntu Mate 18.04.
If I look at these processes I get 2 istances:
`ps aux | grep mate-settings-daemon

linofex   3003  0.0  0.0   4624   800 ?        S    09:37   0:00 /bin/sh -c mate-settings-daemon
linofex   3005  0.0  0.5 1340260 42640 ?       Sl   09:37   0:01 mate-settings-daemon`

where the second line refers to `exec` in i3 config file.

This happens for all the programs that I put in the `config`.

The reason why I put `nm-applet` is to show the icon try on the bar.

I tried to uncheck them in the `startup programs` applet, but nothing changes

Is that normal, or should I do something to solve?

Comment: Some of the processes may already be started by XDG autostart, so launching them again after logging into a desktop environment will start them once more (if the app itself does not "notice/check" it is already loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the processes may already be started through XDG autostart. When any user logs in, processes defined in /etc/xdg/autostart are automatically started. That includes the daemons that your desktop environment uses.

These processes are described using `.desktop` files, text files with the same format as these used to populate the application menu. However, they include a line `NoDisplay=true` to prevent them from showing up in your menu.

In principle, desktop specific `.desktop` files also should contain an entry that limits their execution to that specific desktop environment. Such line looks like `OnlyShowIn=MATE;`. This line will make sure the desktop file is not used (as if it would not exist) except in the listed desktop environments. The system is informed about the current desktop through the environmental variable `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.

Thus, in your i3 session
1) Check whether `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is set or correctly set.
2) Check whether the `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` that corresponds with `mate-settings-daemon` does contain the appropriate `OnlyShowIn` line.

Comment: Yes, `mate-settings-daemon` and `mate-power-manager` have `OnlyShowIn=MATE;`. But if I edit these lines and I reboot the session not in i3, but in the classic environment, will these programs start?

Comment: What gives `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`? What happens if you comment out `exec_always --no-startup-id mate-settings-daemon` in i3-config?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` shows `i3`. If I comment `exec_always --no-startup-id mate-settings-daemon` then my graphic goes very ugly and `ps aux` doesn't show either of the two lines `linofex   3003  0.0  0.0   4624   800 ?        S    09:37   0:00 /bin/sh -c mate-settings-daemon
linofex   3005  0.0  0.5 1340260 42640 ?       Sl   09:37   0:01 mate-settings-daemon`

Comment: Try changing `exec-always` to `exec`, reboot and see whether you still have the 2 processes.

Comment: Yes, I still have both